# How specify element name in list?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

Here is a model and data list definitions:

```
<!-- DataLists-->
<type name="sc:contractType">
    <title>Options</title>
    <parent>dl:dataListItem</parent>
    <properties>
        <property name="sc:type">
            <title>Type</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
        </property>
    </properties>
</type>

<!-- workflow model-->
<type name="sc:startProcesstask">
    <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
    <properties>
        <property name="sc:helloName">
            <type>d:text</type>
            <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            <multiple>false</multiple>
        </property>
    </properties>
   <associations>
       <child-association name="sc:requestCategory"">
           <target>
              <class>sc:contractType</class>
              <mandatory>true</mandatory>
              <many>false</many>
            </target>
        </child-association>
    </associations>
</type>
```

When I edit model and try select data list item value I have to:

1. browse entire repository for finding data list item.
2. see UUID value instead of `type` property in item list.

Is there a way to tell alfresco to show `type` property insted of UUID during browsing for list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the default form control for selecting the target of that child association is not sufficient for your needs. So, you need to provide an alternative custom form control. The [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html) show how to do this using a very simplified example.

Comment: Also default forms which is used when no form is specified can be viewed [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/tree/master/share/src/main/resources/alfresco)